# "Cannot connect to the debugged process" with Ruby on Netbeans

Tags: ruby, rubygems, netbeans-8

I have installed Netbeans 8.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.  I have installed the plugin 1434628827_ruby_and_rails.  I have ruby-debug, version 0.10.5.rc2, installed along with ruby-debug-base(0.10.5.rc2 java) and ruby-debug-ide (0.4.17.beta14).

I start a new project with the option "Ruby Application".  I enter some code, try to run it in debug mode and nothing happens.  I then choose

```
Attach Debugger ...
```

I take the default options

```
Debugger: Ruby Debugger (ruby-debug-ide)
Host: localhost
Port: 7000
Timeout [2]: 15
```

After 15 seconds, I get the message

```
Problem occurred during debugger start: Cannot connect to the debugged process at port 7000 in 15s
```